# Can't install data tools platform in Aptana Studio 3 -- cannot satisfy dependency

Tags: eclipse, plugins, dependencies, installation

I'm trying to install the following plugins in the standalone version of Aptana Studio 3 on Mac OS X Lion (build 3.0.7.201112151935):

- Data Tools Platform Enablement Extender SDK
- Data Tools Platform Extender SDK

I'm using the Indigo Eclipse update site (http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo) to try to install these plugins. However, when I try to install them, I get this error:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Data Tools Platform Extender SDK 1.9.1.v201108301820-7PA37JFEPPYv06-0y5OPQMV3opyi (org.eclipse.datatools.sdk.feature.feature.group 1.9.1.v201108301820-7PA37JFEPPYv06-0y5OPQMV3opyi)
  Software currently installed: Aptana Studio 3 3.0.7.201112151935-15122011194114 (com.aptana.rcp.product 3.0.7.201112151935-15122011194114)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Equinox Provisioning Repository Tools 2.0.100.v20110512-1320 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.tools 2.0.100.v20110512-1320)
    Equinox p2 repository tools. 2.0.1.R36x_v20100823 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.tools 2.0.1.R36x_v20100823)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Aptana Studio 3 3.0.7.201112151935-15122011194114 (com.aptana.rcp.product 3.0.7.201112151935-15122011194114)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.tools [2.0.1.R36x_v20100823]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: DTP SDK Plug-in 1.7.0.v200906161850 (org.eclipse.datatools.sdk 1.7.0.v200906161850)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.pde.ui [3.2.0,4.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Data Tools Platform Extender SDK 1.9.1.v201108301820-7PA37JFEPPYv06-0y5OPQMV3opyi (org.eclipse.datatools.sdk.feature.feature.group 1.9.1.v201108301820-7PA37JFEPPYv06-0y5OPQMV3opyi)
    To: org.eclipse.datatools.sdk [1.7.0.v200906161850]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: PDE UI 3.6.100.v20110603 (org.eclipse.pde.ui 3.6.100.v20110603)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.tools [2.0.100,3.0.0)
```

I read [here](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-8848) that the problem may be in the feature.xml file, but this was for a different plugin and with a different version of Eclipse.

I'd really appreciate your help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is that the case Eclipse version for the Aptana Studio is different than Indigo (which is what the DTP stuff requires from the update site). (The things that are conflicting are p2 projects which are part of the base Eclipse).

I recommend that you download Eclipse Indigo from eclipse.org and then install the Aptana Studio as plugins and then try to install the DTP stuff.

Alternatively find out which version your Aptana Studio 3 is based on (you can go to Help -> About and click the Installation Details button) and then install the DTP tools from the Eclipse update site that corresponds to that.